# XPath nested query with Ids

Tags: html, xpath

I using XPath queries with finding some elements in HTML page but it's not working as expected. I want to find checkbox inside element TR with id="row1". Checkbox has neither name nor id.

My page looks like this:

```
<table>                
<thead>
 <tr>...</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                            
     <tr id="row1">
      <td class="center">
        <div class="aaa">
          <label >
            <span >AA</span>        
            <input type="checkbox">
```

My query was/is:

```
tr[@id='row1']/input[@type='checkbox']
tr[id='row1']//input[@type='checkbox']
tr[@id='row1']//input[@type='checkbox']
```

but none of them works.

Comment: try: `//tr[@id='row1']//input[@type='checkbox']`

Comment: It works:) Thanks

Comment: derloopkat: please provide your comment as answer. @p-k you could then vote and accept it.